# Automating "for loop" in R for the whole data set and counting

Tags: r, dataframe, loops, for-loop, purrr

I am doing an analysis and I am not so advanced in R. I am stuck in this stage. I would appreciate your cordial help in this regard.

In the example data set (`data1`), I have 7 columns (`a, b, c, d, e, f, g`). First 3 columns (`a, b, c`) are from one group and the other 4 columns (`d, e, f, g`) are from different group.

In my `data1`, I applied a formula for TRUE/FALSE (1/0) output for each and every combination pair from the 2 groups [a with every column of d, e, f, g (`ad, ae, af, ag`); b with every column (`bd, be, bf, bg`); c with every column (`cd, ce, cf, cg`)]. In my example, I tried to do it for c and d column (`cd`). But, it is not showing me the correct output. In my desired output, the second output should be 1 (TRUE). And also, I have no idea how to automate the loop for the whole data set.

**N.B. Since any value of parental line can satisfy the conditions, I used **|** in the loop to get the result. But, I am not sure if it is the correct or efficient way.

```r
a <- c(0, 0.501, 0.501, 0, 0.57, 20)
b <- c(0.108, 0.96, 0.110, 0.10, 4, 2)
c <- c(0.110, 1, 0.118, 0.107, 0.34, 0.019)
d <- c(0.115, 0.113, 0.98, 0.1, 13, 2)
e <- c(1, 3.113, 0.98, 0.560, 0.15, 1)
f <- c(2.45, 4.16, 0.045, 0.9, 0.12, 70)
g <- c(2, 0.6, 3, 7, 0.12, 29)

data1 <- data.frame(a, b, c, d, e, f, g)
rownames(data1) <- c(("Man2"), paste0('Man', 4:8))
data1
#>           a     b     c      d     e      f     g
#> Man2  0.000 0.108 0.110  0.115 1.000  2.450  2.00
#> Man4  0.501 0.960 1.000  0.113 3.113  4.160  0.60
#> Man5  0.501 0.110 0.118  0.980 0.980  0.045  3.00
#> Man6  0.000 0.100 0.107  0.100 0.560  0.900  7.00
#> Man7  0.570 4.000 0.340 13.000 0.150  0.120  0.12
#> Man8 20.000 2.000 0.019  2.000 1.000 70.000 29.00
r <- c(1:6) #number of rows
c <- c(1:7)  #number of cols
f <- c(1:3) #first group (a, b, c)
s <- c(4:7)  #second group (d, e, f, g)

for (i in r) {
    if ((data1[i,3] >= 0.5 & data1[i,4] >= data1[i, 3]*2) | (data1[i,4] >= 0.5 & data1[i,3] >= data1[i,4]*2)) {
      print(1L)
    } else if ((data1[i,3] < 0.5  & data1[i,4] >= 1.0) | (data1[i,4] < 0.5 & data1[1,3] >= 1.0)) {
      print(1L)
    } else {
      print(0L)
    }
  }
#> [1] 0
#> [1] 0
#> [1] 0
#> [1] 0
#> [1] 1
#> [1] 1
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

For each combination,

- if the value in any one column is **>= 0.5**, the value in the other column should be **>= 2** folds,
- and if the value is below **0.5** in any one column, the value in the other column need to be **>= 1** for each row.

I look for an output like this `df`:

```r
ad <- c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L)
ae <- c(1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L)
af <- c(1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L)
ag <- c(1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L)
bd <- c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L)
be <- c(1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L)
bf <- c(1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L)
bg <- c(1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L)
cd <- c(0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L)
ce <- c(1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L)
cf <- c(1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L)
cg <- c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L)
df <- data.frame(ad, ae, af, ag, bd, be, bf, bg, cd, ce, cf, cg)
rownames(df) <- c(("Man2"), paste0('Man', 4:8))
df
#>      ad ae af ag bd be bf bg cd ce cf cg
#> Man2  0  1  1  1  0  1  1  1  0  1  1  1
#> Man4  0  1  1  0  0  1  1  0  1  1  1  1
#> Man5  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  1
#> Man6  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  1
#> Man7  1  0  0  0  1  1  1  1  1  0  0  0
#> Man8  1  1  1  0  0  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

I have two groups in the combination pairs as well. I want to count number of "1s" in one group `c(ad, ae, bg, be, bf, cd)` and also in the other group `c(af, ag, bd, ce, cf, cg)` for each row. Is it a good idea to save the 1/0 output in a new data frame like `df` or just putting the count of "1s" in two new columns (like in `df2`)? The working data set is a huge one. So, memory and efficient way are the issues here.
My desired output is something like this [counting 1s for the first combination group `c(ad, ae, bg, be, bf, cd)` and also counting 1s for the second combination group `c(af, ag, bd, ce, cf, cg)` for each row]:

```r
ad <- c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L)
ae <- c(1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L)
af <- c(1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L)
ag <- c(1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L)
bd <- c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L)
be <- c(1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L)
bf <- c(1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L)
bg <- c(1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L)
cd <- c(0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L)
ce <- c(1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L)
cf <- c(1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L)
cg <- c(1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L)
#first_group <- c(ad, ae, bg, be, bf, cd)
#second_group <- c(af, ag, bd, ce, cf, cg) 
first_combi <- c(4, 4, 1, 1, 5, 5)
second_combi <- c(5, 3, 2, 2, 1, 4)
df2 <- data.frame(ad, ae, af, ag, bd, be, bf, bg, cd, ce, cf, cg, first_combi, second_combi)
rownames(df2) <- c(("Man2"), paste0('Man', 4:8))
df2
#>      ad ae af ag bd be bf bg cd ce cf cg first_combi second_combi
#> Man2  0  1  1  1  0  1  1  1  0  1  1  1           4            5
#> Man4  0  1  1  0  0  1  1  0  1  1  1  0           4            3
#> Man5  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  1           1            2
#> Man6  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  1           1            2
#> Man7  1  0  0  0  1  1  1  1  1  0  0  0           5            1
#> Man8  1  1  1  0  0  1  1  1  1  1  1  1           5            4
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

**So, I need two suggestions:**

1. How to automate the loop for the whole data set
2. How to store the 1/0 (TRUE/FALSE) for the two combination groups and counting "1s" for the groups.

Please, pave me on these two problems with the data set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a function for the comparison and loop the columns to get the results in a dataframe. Then, use `lapply()` to run `table()` through each column of the dataframe to get the number of 1s.

```
# A function for the comparison
compare <- function(x, y) {
  ifelse(
    (x >= 0.5 & y >= (x * 2)) | (y >= 0.5 & x >= (y * 2)) | (x < 0.5 & y >= 1) | (y < 0.5 & x >= 1),
    1L, 0L
  )
}

# Get all combinations
comb <- expand.grid(first = c("a", "b", "c"),
                    second = c("d", "e",  "f", "g"),
                    stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
n <- nrow(comb)

# Create an empty list
res <- vector("list", n)

for (i in seq_len(n)) {
  res[[i]] <- compare(data1[[ comb$first[i] ]],
                      data1[[ comb$second[i] ]])
}

# Assign names to the list
names(res) <- paste0(comb$first, comb$second, collpase = "")
# Convert the list to a dataframe
res <- list2DF(res)
# Assign row names
rownames(res) <- c(("Man2"), paste0('Man', 4:8))

res

#      ad bd cd ae be ce af bf cf ag bg cg
# Man2  0  0  0  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
# Man4  0  0  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  0  0  0
# Man5  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  1  1
# Man6  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  1  1
# Man7  1  1  1  0  1  0  0  1  0  0  1  0
# Man8  1  0  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  0  1  1

# use lapply to get the counts of 1s and 0s in each column
res_count <- lapply(res, table)
res_count

# $ad
# 
# 0 1 
# 4 2 
# 
# $bd
# 
# 0 1 
# 5 1 
# 
# $cd
# 
# 0 1 
# 3 3 
# <omitted>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Zaw and again sorry for being late. It works perfect for the first part. For the counting I have updated my question. I think my query was not perfectly described. I hope the question is clear now to guide me.

Answer (score 3):

`tidyverse` strategy.  For the second part I'm Assuming you want colsums in matrix form.

- I have divided your column-names into two groups say `grp_1` and `grp_2`
- `exapnd.grid` will generate all combinations of both name groups
- next we will pass this into `pmap_dfc` as its first argument
- for the function part, I have

  - stored the logical values into a temp variable `x` say.  Before storing I have wrapped whole condition with `+` which converts logical values to numeric
  - next I have set names for this x as per group combinations using `paste0`
- Since `pmap_dfc` is used, the results will be binded into columns automatically
- last code restores the row names

For the second part I have used -

- `outer` function, in combination with
- `colSums`.

Using `colSums` will directly give you results as per column names instead of a matrix

```r
library(tidyverse)

#optimised solution #for the loop part
gr_1 <- c('a', 'b', 'c')
gr_2 <- c('d', 'e', 'f', 'g')

expand.grid(gr_1, gr_2, stringsAsFactors = F) %>%
  pmap_dfc(~ {x <- +((data1[[..1]] >= 0.5 & data1[[..2]] >  2 * data1[[..1]]) |
                       (data1[[..2]] >= 0.5 & data1[[..1]] >  2 * data1[[..2]]) | 
                       (data1[[..2]] < 0.5 &  data1[[..1]] >= 1) |
                       (data1[[..1]] < 0.5 &  data1[[..2]] >= 1)); setNames(list(x), paste0(..1, ..2))} ) %>%
  as.data.frame() %>%
  `rownames<-`(rownames(data1)) -> res

res
#>      ad bd cd ae be ce af bf cf ag bg cg
#> Man2  0  0  0  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
#> Man4  0  0  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  0  0  0
#> Man5  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  1  1
#> Man6  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  1  1
#> Man7  1  1  1  0  1  0  0  1  0  0  1  0
#> Man8  1  0  1  1  0  1  1  1  1  0  1  1
```

Second part

```
#second part
out_gr1 <- c('ad', 'ae', 'bg', 'be', 'bf', 'cd')

split.default(res,  c('Gr1', 'Gr2')[1 + !(names(res) %in% out_gr1)]) %>%
  sapply(rowSums)
  
     Gr1 Gr2
Man2   4   5
Man4   4   3
Man5   1   2
Man6   1   2
Man7   5   1
Man8   5   4
```

---

Doing it in one pipe

```
gr_1 <- c('a', 'b', 'c')
gr_2 <- c('d', 'e', 'f', 'g')
out_gr1 <- c('ad', 'ae', 'bg', 'be', 'bf', 'cd')

expand.grid(gr_1, gr_2, stringsAsFactors = F) %>%
  pmap_dfc(~ {x <- +((data1[[..1]] >= 0.5 & data1[[..2]] >  2 * data1[[..1]]) |
                       (data1[[..2]] >= 0.5 & data1[[..1]] >  2 * data1[[..2]]) | 
                       (data1[[..2]] < 0.5 &  data1[[..1]] >= 1) |
                       (data1[[..1]] < 0.5 &  data1[[..2]] >= 1)); setNames(list(x), paste0(..1, ..2))} ) %>%
  as.data.frame() %>%
  `rownames<-`(rownames(data1)) %>% cbind(split.default(., c('First_combi', 'Second_combi')[1 + !(names(.) %in% out_gr1)]) %>%
  sapply(rowSums))

     ad bd cd ae be ce af bf cf ag bg cg First_combi Second_combi
Man2  0  0  0  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1           4            5
Man4  0  0  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  0  0  0           4            3
Man5  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  1  1           1            2
Man6  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  1  1           1            2
Man7  1  1  1  0  1  0  0  1  0  0  1  0           5            1
Man8  1  0  1  1  0  1  1  1  1  0  1  1           5            4
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, @AnilGoyal. I am sorry for being late to reply. It was a hectic day for me and I got sick. The first part worked 100% right. About the second part: I was supposed to count the 1s for each row for two combination groups. I admit that my query was not clear enough. I updated the last part of my question (with reproducible data). Hope it will work.

Comment: I am looking row-wise to count total number of `1`s in `ad, ae, bg, be, bf, cd`columns (first combination group) which is 4, and then again counting number of total `1`s in `af, ag, bd, ce, cf, cg` columns (the second  combination group) which is 5 for the first row (`Man2`). The same two-times counting for each of the rows will be followed. Does it help elaborating the second part?

Comment: yes, they have grouping criteria. They (`ad, bd, cd, ae, be, ce, af, bf, cf, ag, bg, cg`) have some other values and depending on those I spliced them into two equal groups where any member of the first group has higher values than the second group.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the following solution:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

# First we create every combinations of column names between 2 groups
expand.grid(names(data1)[1:3], names(data1[4:7])) -> cols

# Then we check your desired conditions
map2(cols$Var1, cols$Var2, ~ data1[, c(.x, .y)]) %>%
  map(~ .x %>% 
        mutate(!!paste0(names(.x), collapse = "") :=  
                 pmap_dbl(.x, ~ {x <- c(...)[-3];
                 if((..1 > 0.5 & ..2 >= ..1 * 2) | (..2 > 0.5 & ..1 >= ..2 * 2) |
                    (..1 < 0.5 & ..2 >= 1) | (..2 < 0.5 & ..1 >= 1)) {
                   1
                 } else {
                   0
                 }}))) %>%
  map_dfc(~ .x %>% select(3)) -> df

  ad bd cd ae be ce af bf cf ag bg cg
1  0  0  0  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
2  0  0  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  0  0  0
3  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  1  1
4  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  1  1
5  1  1  1  0  1  0  0  1  0  0  1  0
6  1  0  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  0  1  1
```

With regard to your second question, if I understood what you are looking for correctly and you would like to count the number of `1` for each row in each pair, you can use this:

```
col1 <- c("ad", "ae", "bg", "be", "bf", "cd")
col2 <- c("af", "ag", "bd", "ce", "cf", "cg")

split.default(df, names(df) %in% col1) %>%
  map(~ .x %>% 
        rowwise() %>%
        mutate(count = reduce(cur_data(), `+`)))

$`FALSE`
# A tibble: 6 x 7
# Rowwise: 
     bd    ce    af    cf    ag    cg count
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     0     1     1     1     1     1     5
2     0     1     1     1     0     0     3
3     0     0     0     0     1     1     2
4     0     0     0     0     1     1     2
5     1     0     0     0     0     0     1
6     0     1     1     1     0     1     4

$`TRUE`
# A tibble: 6 x 7
# Rowwise: 
     ad    cd    ae    be    bf    bg count
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     0     0     1     1     1     1     4
2     0     1     1     1     1     0     4
3     0     0     0     0     0     1     1
4     0     0     0     0     0     1     1
5     1     1     0     1     1     1     5
6     1     1     1     1     1     1     6
```

In order to calculate the euclidean distance you could use the following solution:

```
gr_1 <- c('a', 'b', 'c')
gr_2 <- c('d', 'e', 'f', 'g')

expand.grid(gr_1, gr_2) %>%
  {map2(.$Var1, .$Var2, ~ data1[c(.x, .y)])} %>%
  map_dfc(~ .x %>%
        summarise(!!sym(paste0(names(.x), collapse = "")) := sqrt(sum((.x[[1]] - .x[[2]]) ^ 2))))

        ad       bd       cd       ae       be       ce       af       bf       cf       ag
1 21.88397 9.081539 12.87361 19.22347 4.714029 2.683949 50.20569 68.23066 70.09625 11.85147
        bg       cg
1 28.35006 29.99164
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, @Anoushiravan R and sorry for being late. The first part is correct. The second part should be a bit modified. Yes, I want to count row-wise, but for two combination groups. I don't understand how to count number of `1`s for these two combinations.

Comment: @Rasheduzzaman You're welcome. I think if the combination of variables in the pair is correct, since our values are binary when we count the sum of rows we in fact count the number of `1`s in each row. But let me know if it should be modified in some other ways.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @Anoshiravan R. You are right. I misunderstood the matter. So, my problem is solved! :)
Take care!

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping me out. I am obliged by your cordiality!

Comment: That's very kind of you. If you needed any more help with this question just let us know here.

Comment: Yes, I will definitely seek your help and suggestions.

Comment: Hello, @Anoushiravan R. How can I calculate the Euclidian distance  e.g. _sqrt((data1[, "a"] - data1[, "d"])**2)_ from the `data1` dataset for the same combinations (`ad, ae, af, ag, bd, be, bf, bg, cd, ce, cf, cg` )?

Comment: @Rasheduzzaman Hi please check my updates :)

Comment: your output is fine. But I don't know why I am getting a wrong output. 
#' aa.1      ba       ca      ab bb.1       cb       ac       bc cc.1       ad       bd       cd
#'  0 18.3344 19.99281 18.3344    0 4.161932 19.99281 4.161932    0 21.88397 9.081539 12.87361

Comment: You may check the formula again and parentheses, since it was fairly a simple calculation.